# Android manifest permissions not matching up with runtime permissions

Tags: android, testing, permissions, instrumentation

bit of a strange question.

I'm trying to write some code that, for testing purposes, allows my test instance of Instrumentation to programmatically add Call Logs. It is simple but to do this, but it requires the android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG permission.

I've added this in my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG"/>
```

But when I use this code during runtime...

```
PackageManager instrumentationPM = instrumentationContext.getPackageManager();
PackageInfo info = instrumentationPM.getPackageInfo(PACKAGE_NAME,
    PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
PermissionInfo[] permission_info = info.permissions;
```

The permission_info (aka info.permissions) array is null. Thus, during runtime no permissions are detected. Any clue what could be the issue here, and if this is at all relevant to my task of allowing my Instrumentation to add call logs?

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will not return the `<uses-permission>` specified manifest file. Instead it will return the `<permission>`, which is system level [permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestPermission).

I tried this code:

```
    PackageManager instrumentationPM = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
    PackageInfo info;
    try {
        info = instrumentationPM.getPackageInfo("com.example.testingproj",
            PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
        PermissionInfo[] permission_info = info.permissions;
        if(permission_info!=null)
            System.out.println(permission_info.length);
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And I have kept this permission in my manifest file:

```
<permission android:name="anypermission"></permission>
```

It gives me length = 1 in logcat.

I am not aware of getting all the `<uses-permission>` from manifest. But if you just want to check if there is a specific permission in manifest, you can try this:

```
    if (instrumentationPM.checkPermission(permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, getPackageName()) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        System.out.println("wifi state permission");
    } else {
        // do something
    }
```